Ranking discriminator and loss
A ranking discriminator D(z1, z2, z3 ) ∈ [0, 1] that should be high if
_z1 ∼ p1 , z2 ∼ p2 , z3 ∼ p3 _ and low otherwise. For finding the loss and optimal discriminator D(z1 , z2 , z3 ) should I modify GAN loss or Bradley-Terry model for this task?
